# tomcat JNDI 128-bit encryption

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption, hash

Most of the sample I found online is Base64 encoding, not really encryption for the username password for database access.  Our requirement is those info can't be store in clear text and has to be in 128-bit encryption.  We do have DSN setup since this database will be accessed from a .NET application as well.  Worst case I can use JDBC-ODBC bridge even though it's not recommended approach by Sun.

Does anyone have any experience on how to encypt the username / password into 128-bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Base64 isn't encryption, it's encoding - and almost as insecure as plain text.

For encryption, maybe look at the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) APIs.

However, there shouldn't really be any need to decrypt a password - it's far better to use one-way hashing ([MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), SHA-1 etc).